# MultiSelect Listbox issues

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having an issue making a listbox into a multiselect listbox. I understand that the code to make a listbox multiselect is:

```
[forms]![formname]![listboxname].multiselect=2
```

However when I run this in Private Sub Form_Load() I get run-time error '2448' You can't assign a value to this object.

I guess I don't understand how to make a listbox multiselect, but I am pretty sure I understand how to use the multiselect listbox in VBA.

Any help on how to use the above code to actually change the listbox to multiselect would be appreciated.

Comment: I've also tried Forms("formname").Controls("listboxname").multiselect=2

Comment: The easiest way is in the Form Designer. Right-click the ListBox, choose *Properties*; in the Properties Sheet, click the *Other* tab and set *MultiSelect* to either *Simple* or *Extended*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Microsoft Office Help on property `MultiSelect`:

> This property can be set only in form Design view.

Set this property in Form Design, and don't try to change it in code.

**Some examples of working with MultiSelect:**

```
' Retrieve all selected values
Public Function ListBoxGetMultiSelect(ByVal rListBox As Access.ListBox) As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim vList As Variant
    vList = ""
    With rListBox
        For Each v In .ItemsSelected
            vList = vList & .Column(0, v) & vbCrLf
        Next
    End With
    ListBoxGetMultiSelect = vList
End Function

' clear all selected values
Public Sub ListBoxClearSelection(ByVal rListBox As Access.ListBox)
    Dim v As Variant
    With rListBox
        For Each v In .ItemsSelected
            .Selected(v) = False
        Next
        .Value = Null
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, do you you understand how to access the info from the multiselect listbox in vba? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121356
This seems overly complicated, but it does in the end what I want. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Wow, that is an old link! (Access 2.0) See newly added code samples in answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to set Multiselect Property via Vba Code:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings = False
    DoCmd.OpenForm myformname, acDesign
    Forms(myformname).SetFocus
    Forms(myformname).Controls(List3).MultiSelect = 0
    DoCmd.Close acForm, myformname
DoCmd.SetWarnings = True
```